# Unable to cancel a EJB 3.0 Timer

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I am trying cancel EJB timers in my application through the following code:

```
Collection <Timer>timers = timerService.getTimers();

System.out.println("logtimer: No of Active timers = "+timers.size());
if(timers != null){
    for (Timer timer : timers) {
        System.out.println("logtimer: About to cancel Timer "+timer.toString());
        if(timer.getInfo()!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            System.out.println("logtimer: Cancelled Timer "+timer.getInfo());
        }
    }
}
```

However eventhough I have 3 active timers at present the `timer.getInfo()` method call always returns a null. What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer.getInfo() returns the value you specified when you created the timer (or if you used `@Schedule`, the info is specified via that annotation).  If it returns null, that means you didn't specify a value.